# How get the actual emailbody of email sent as riche text using PidTagRtfCompressed Canonical Property

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the emailbody of the email, using ews java 2.0, sent in rich text format.

Though I am getting the text format correctly, but i am not receiving the html format of the same.

All I need is the exact representation of the emailbody in which the email was sent. So that I could reproduce the same in another system which requires html.

Is it possible for me to get it?

I tried using the  PidTagRtfCompressed Canonical Property. I defined an extended property using the extended property definition with the corresponding tag(0x1009) and mapitype(binary) for the rtf emailbody. Though i did receive value in it but I am not able decode it to the corresponding readable value.

Would it be possible to get the readable value out of this extended property? Would it be possible to get the html format as well?

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> > I am trying to get the emailbody of the email, using ews java 2.0, sent in rich text format.

If you just request the body using a GetItem operation EWS will return HTML, if the message has a Native RTF body the Exchange Store will do an on the fly conversion of the RTF message into HTML (the meta information in the HTML returned will tell you if a conversion has been done). You can test this without writing any code using the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ . Is there any reason your not using the Strongly typed properties as this would be the normal method of getting the body the rest of your question doesn't make much sense unless you have a problem with the Store conversion ?

> > Though i did receive value in it but I am not able decode it to the corresponding readable value.

If you want to that then you need to implement your own decompression library to do this eg something like https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader/blob/master/MsgReader/Outlook/RtfDecompressor.cs should work. The protocol spec for this is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463890(v=exchg.80).aspx . Exchange has a library to do that but its limited in use to the server only as it mostly for use in Transport agents https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.textconverters(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for the response. I am actually trying to to get both the text as well as html form of the email body in one call. So i tried the approach where we set the property as text and use one extended property to get the html form of the email body. But using this approach when an email with rich text format is received the extended property(which gets the html form) value is not received. So to cater this problem i tried using the the rtf mapi tag.

Comment: But now i see that the respective extended property of email body ic only coming when the email in the corresponding form. That is, if email is sent in html form then only the extended property with the PR_BODY_HTML mapi tag is getting received similarly for PR_BODY and PR_RTF_COMPRESS
ED. Not sure what should i do to receive the text and html form when the email is received in any the three format. Would it possible for you guide me?

Comment: Also the the generic emailMessage.getBody() method also doesn't give the html form if the email is received as plain text.

Comment: You won't be able to get both in one call unless you get MimeContent and then process the bodies from that content (and you will only get both in this if both where set in the original). The body that is returned by GetItem depends on the BodyType you ask for in the request if the message only has Text or RTF body and your GetItem Request asks for HTML then the Exchange store will return HTML. You can test this easily using the EWSEditor (eg try a contact or appointment as these have RTF body by default)

Comment: Well now i have placed two calls to generalize the whole process. But now the only problem is when the email is sent as plain text I am not getting the HTML form of the email using the getBody() method of the EmailMessage class(I do get it in case of rich text). Any idea if it is possible to have the html form in this case?

Comment: I can only guess you code is incorrect eg your GetItem request that isn't requesting the HTML body. Have you tried using the EWSEditor ? that will tell you if its your code or something else

Comment: I tried using the EWSEditor but it is not able to connect to the server and failing with the authorization error. I did look into the mimecontent of the EmailMessage(for the email sent as plain text), and even that is not containing the html format of the email body, while for the other format email(sent as html or rtf) it is having the html format email content.

Comment: The mimecontent is only going to contain a HTML body if one was set in the Message. GetItem will return a store converted body if no HTML body was set if you request it (requires correct code). The Best body alogorythm https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463905(v=exchg.80).aspx explains this. My advice would in the instance you don't have HTML body and you don't want to make another GetItem call to exchange just use a library to convert the textbody you have to HTML (that all the Store is going to do anyway).